# Can this be done in a Elastic Search Query?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, ranking, elastica

I am currently solving this by pre-calculating a score before inserting the events into Elastic Search. However because it is based on a date I have to recalculate the score daily. Would it be possible to do this calculation during a query?

Data:

```
{
    "title" : "event 1",
    "rank" : 1034, // pre-calculated score
    "score": 34,
    "date" : "2015-10-10 00:00:00",
    "meta" : [
        {
            "date": "2015-10-10 00:00:00",
            "type": "insert"
        },
        {
            "date": "2015-12-10 00:00:00",
            "type": "outsert"
        },
        {
            "date": "2015-05-10 00:00:00",
            "type": "other"
        }       
    ]
}
```

Ranking:

There are 4 "buckets" created using the `insert` date.

- Events under 5 days old
- Events over 5 days and under 10 days old
- Events over 10 days and under 15 days old
- Events older than 15 days

Events in each bucket need to be sorted by the `score` field `DESC`.

The pre-calculated rank is made by adding 1000, 2000 or 3000 to the score depending in which bucket the Event falls.

When a query is made the results are sorted by Rank.

How would I do this without using a pre-calculated `rank`?

Answer (score 1):

i think you can achieve this.The real pain with your current predefined scoring logic is that you cannot move event data backwards after its expiration in his current bucket.since your buckets follow days difference symmetry of 5 days.Use function score with linear day,scale -5 days.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

```
{
 "gauss": {
        "date_field": {
              "origin": "2013-09-17", 
              "scale": "5d",
              "offset": "0d", 
              "decay" : 0.5 
            }
        }
    }
```

Replace origin with current date when querying the data.setup the boost_mode and score_mode according to the link shared.
Hope this works.

Comment: sorry instead of gauss decay use linear decay.